# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text': Cant get the text input from MDTextField kivyMD python

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to get the text from my `MDTextField` in the `MainScreen` but getting the error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\\IdanStudy\\readmedy\\main.py", line 42, in \<module\>
> MainApp().run()
> File "C:\\ProgramData\\Anacondafolder\\lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\app.py", line 955, in run
> self.\_run_prepare()
> File "C:\\ProgramData\\Anacondafolder\\lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\app.py", line 925, in \_run_prepare
> root = self.build()
> File "C:\\IdanStudy\\readmedy\\main.py", line 38, in build
> return Builder.load_file("ui_kivy.kv")
> File "C:\\ProgramData\\Anacondafolder\\lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\lang\\builder.py", line 305, in load_file
> return self.load_string(data, \*\*kwargs)
> File "C:\\ProgramData\\Anacondafolder\\lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\lang\\builder.py", line 407, in load_string
> self.\_apply_rule(
> File "C:\\ProgramData\\Anacondafolder\\lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\lang\\builder.py", line 659, in \_apply_rule
> widget.add_widget(child)
> File "C:\\ProgramData\\Anacondafolder\\lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\uix\\screenmanager.py", line 1001, in add_widget
> self.current = widget.name
> File "kivy\\properties.pyx", line 520, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
> File "kivy\\properties.pyx", line 567, in kivy.properties.Property.set
> File "kivy\\properties.pyx", line 606, in kivy.properties.Property.\_dispatch
> File "kivy_event.pyx", line 1307, in kivy.\_event.EventObservers.dispatch
> File "kivy_event.pyx", line 1213, in kivy.\_event.EventObservers.\_dispatch
> File "C:\\ProgramData\\Anacondafolder\\lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\uix\\screenmanager.py", line 1069, in on_current
> screen.dispatch('on_enter')
> File "kivy_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy.\_event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
> File "C:\\IdanStudy\\readmedy\\main.py", line 16, in on_enter
> val = self.drug_symptom.text
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' <br/>
> Process finished with exit code 1
> ```

The relevant function is the on_press in the mainwindow, `drug_symptom` is the user input to the TextField, when the user input the text and press ENTER the function is triggered.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.bottomnavigation import MDBottomNavigationItem
from loadmed import data


class MainWindow(Screen):
    drug_symptom = ObjectProperty(None)

    def checkbox_click(self, instance, value, topping):
        print(topping,value)

    def on_enter(self):
        val = self.drug_symptom.text
        if data.get_by_name(val) is None :
            self.drug_symptom.text = ""
            data.med_by_simp(val)
        else:
            self.drug_symptom.text = ""
            print(data.get_by_name(val))

class SearchWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass



class MainApp(MDApp):


    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"
        return Builder.load_file("ui_kivy.kv")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SearchWindow:


<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"

    drug_symptom: drug_symptom



    BoxLayout:
        orientation : "vertical"

        MDTopAppBar:
            title:"ReadMedy"
            md_bg_color: .2,.2,.2,1
            specific_text_color: 1,1,1,1


        MDBottomNavigation:
            panel_color: .2, .2, .2, 1


            MDBottomNavigationItem:

                name: "screen 1"
                text : "Search"
                icon : "home"


                FloatLayout:
                    size : root.width, root.height
                    spacing:30
                    padding: 30

                    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                        text : "Scan"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5,"center_y": .7}
                        size_hint:(0.15, 0.15)
                        md_bg_color: 170/255, 128/255, 255/255


                    MDTextField:
                        id: drug_symptom
                        hint_text: "Drug Name/Symptom"
                        mode: "round"
                        max_text_length: 30
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5,"center_y": .3}
                        size_hint_x: .5
                        line_color_focus: 0, 0, 1, 1
                        foreground_color : (1,0,0,1)
                        multiline : False
                        on_text_validate: root.on_enter()





            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: "screen 2"
                text : "Inventory"
                icon : "youtube"

                MDLabel:
                    text: "yyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
                    halign : "center"


            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: "screen 3"
                text : "settings"
                icon : "cog"



                MDScrollView:

                    do_scroll_y: True
                    do_scroll_x: False
                    size_hint: (1, 1)

                    MDGridLayout:
                        cols:1
                        size_hint_y: None
                        size_hint_x: 0.7
                        size: root.width,root.height
                        #height: self.minimum_height

                        MDFloatLayout:

                            size_hint:(1, 0.05)

                            MDIconButton:
                                icon: "account"
                                pos_hint: {"center_x": .73,"top": 1}


                        MDGridLayout:
                            cols : 2

                            Label :
                                text : "Full Note"
                                font_size : 15

                            MDCheckbox:
                                active: True
                                on_active : root.checkbox_click(self,self.active,"Pepperoni")


                            Label :
                                text : "Prescription"
                                font_size : 15

                            MDCheckbox:
                                on_active : root.checkbox_click(self,self.active,"Cheese")


                            Label :
                                text : "Age of Use"
                                font_size : 15

                            MDCheckbox:
                                on_active : root.checkbox_click(self,self.active,"Mashroom")

                            Label :
                                text : "Instructions"
                                font_size : 15

                            MDCheckbox:
                                on_active : root.checkbox_click(self,self.active,"Pepperoni")


                            Label :
                                text : "Drug Dosage"
                                font_size : 15

                            MDCheckbox:
                                on_active : root.checkbox_click(self,self.active,"Cheese")


                            Label :
                                text : "Side Effects"
                                font_size : 15

                            MDCheckbox:
                                on_active : root.checkbox_click(self,self.active,"Mashroom")

                            Label :
                                text : "Store Method"
                                font_size : 15

                            MDCheckbox:
                                on_active : root.checkbox_click(self,self.active,"Cheese")


                            Label :
                                text : "Ingredients"
                                font_size : 15

                            MDCheckbox:
                                on_active : root.checkbox_click(self,self.active,"Mashroom")







<MDCheckbox>
    size_hint: None, None
    size: "48dp", "48dp"
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .1, 'center_y': .5}
```

I have tried many approaches to this problem and searched for some Questions similar to mine with no success.

The drug_symptom is referred an id on the kv file, the on_enter within the `MDTextField` by `on_text_validate`.
For example, the MDCheckbox with the function `checkbox_click` works just fine so I can't figure the on_enter with the `drug_symptom` prob.